# Kinect V1 c# cant display image properly

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, kinect, kinect-sdk

The code worked fine on *C# WPF application* but is not able to display image properly on `Windows Form application` as I cant create a **writable bitmap** in Form application so tried to create Bitmap from bytes using Lockbits and Marshal Copy method. Is there problem in image format?

[image]

This is my current code. I added a **BytesToBitmap** function to convert bytes to Bitmap in ***PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb*** format.

**Code:**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private KinectSensor sensor;
        private Bitmap colorBmp;
        private Bitmap depthBmp;
        private byte[] colorPxl;
        private byte[] depthPxl;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        public void formLoaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (var potenialK in KinectSensor.KinectSensors)
            {
                ...
            }

            if (null != this.sensor)
            {
                this.sensor.ColorStream.Enable(ColorImageFormat.RgbResolution640x480Fps30);
                this.sensor.DepthStream.Enable(DepthImageFormat.Resolution320x240Fps30);
                this.sensor.SkeletonStream.Enable(); 
                this.colorPxl = new byte[this.sensor.ColorStream.FramePixelDataLength];
                this.colorBmp = new Bitmap(this.sensor.ColorStream.FrameWidth, this.sensor.ColorStream.FrameHeight);
                this.depthBmp = new Bitmap(this.sensor.DepthStream.FrameWidth, this.sensor.DepthStream.FrameHeight);

                this.sensor.AllFramesReady += new EventHandler<AllFramesReadyEventArgs>(SensorAllFrameReady);

                try
                {
                    this.sensor.Start();
                }
                catch (IOException)
                {
                    this.sensor = null;
                }
            }
        }

        private void SensorAllFrameReady(object sender, AllFramesReadyEventArgs e)
        {
            using (ColorImageFrame colorFrame = e.OpenColorImageFrame())
            {
                if (colorFrame != null)
                {
                    colorFrame.CopyPixelDataTo(this.colorPxl);

                    this.pictureBox1.Image = BytesToBitmap(colorPxl, 640, 480);

                }
            }

            using (DepthImageFrame depthFrame = e.OpenDepthImageFrame())
            {
                if (depthFrame != null)
                {
                    depthPxl = GenerateColoredBytes(depthFrame);

                    this.pictureBox2.Image = BytesToBitmap(depthPxl, 320, 240);

                }
            }
        }

        private byte[] GenerateColoredBytes(DepthImageFrame depthFrame)
        {
            ...

            return pixels;
        }

        public static Bitmap BytesToBitmap(byte[] pixelData, int height, int width)
        {
            var bitmap = new Bitmap(width, height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);
            var bitmapData = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, bitmap.PixelFormat);
            var ptr = bitmapData.Scan0;

            Marshal.Copy(pixelData, 0, ptr, pixelData.Length);
            bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);

            return bitmap;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

So this is what worked. On passing the `colorframe` directly to the `BytesToBitmap` function I can see the frame correctly.

Code:

```
public static Bitmap ImageToBitmap(ColorImageFrame Image)
        {
            byte[] pixeldata = new byte[Image.PixelDataLength];
            Image.CopyPixelDataTo(pixeldata);
            Bitmap bmap = new Bitmap(Image.Width, Image.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);
            BitmapData bmapdata = bmap.LockBits(
                new Rectangle(0, 0, Image.Width, Image.Height),
                ImageLockMode.WriteOnly,
                bmap.PixelFormat);
            IntPtr ptr = bmapdata.Scan0;
            Marshal.Copy(pixeldata, 0, ptr, Image.PixelDataLength);
            bmap.UnlockBits(bmapdata);
            return bmap;
        }
```